# MySql Divide for .pct for sports league

Tags: mysql

For some reason, I can't suss out a simple bit of code.

I want to divide 'wins' by 'played' in the code below, so that in my output if you've won 2 out of 4 matches, it displays as .500?

Sure it's simple, an placement is probably key, but I can't fathom it for the life of me!!

```
$result = mysql_query("
    select team, 
    count(*) played, 
    count(case when HomeScore > AwayScore then 1 end) wins, 
    count(case when AwayScore > HomeScore then 1 end) lost, 
    count(case when HomeScore = AwayScore then 1 end) draws,
    sum(HomeScore) ptsfor, 
    sum(AwayScore) ptsagainst,
    sum(HomeScore) - sum(AwayScore) goal_diff, 
    sum(case when HomeScore > AwayScore then 3 else 0 end + case 
    when HomeScore = AwayScore then 1 else 0 end) score     
    from (select 
        HomeTeam team, 
        HomeScore, 
        AwayScore 
    from Game 
        union all 
    select  AwayTeam, 
        AwayScore, 
        HomeScore 
    from Game) a 
    group by team 
    order by wins desc, 
         draws desc,
     lost asc,
     goal_diff desc;");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add another computed column to the query, like so:

```
select team, 
count(*) played, 
count(case when HomeScore > AwayScore then 1 end) wins,
(cast(count(case when HomeScore > AwayScore then 1 end) as decimal(8,2)/cast(count(*) as decimal(8,2)) percentage,
.... -> Rest of the query goes here
```

The casting is done since I assumed that the scores will be integers. Without casting there will be a loss of accuracy i.e. 2/4 will return 0 without casting.

Comment: I now get "Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/peterborough/www/www/leaguetable.php on line 41", which is my while stmt, which worked previously:     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['team'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['wins'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['lost'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['percentage'] . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
      echo "</table>";

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below. This capitalizes on the behavior of MySQL to automatically cast `boolean` expressions as `int`.  So that means no `CASE` statements (pretty queries at the expense of portability).  Also, parts like `SUM(3*win + draw) score` visually looks more like your score computation formula.  No problem computing `pct`.

```
SELECT team
     , COUNT(*)  played
     , SUM(win)  wins
     , SUM(loss) lost
     , SUM(win)/count(*) pctWon
     , SUM(draw) draws
     , SUM(SelfScore) ptsfor
     , SUM(OpponentScore) ptsagainst
     , SUM(SelfScore) - SUM(OpponentScore) goal_diff
     , SUM(3*win + draw) score
FROM (
      SELECT team
     , SelfScore
     , OpponentScore
     , SelfScore < OpponentScore win
     , SelfScore > OpponentScore loss
     , SelfScore = OpponentScore draw
      FROM (
        SELECT HomeTeam team, HomeScore SelfScore, AwayScore OpponentScore
        FROM Game
        union all select AwayTeam, AwayScore, HomeScore
        FROM Game
       ) a
) b
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY wins DESC, draws DESC, lost ASC, goal_diff DESC;
```

Comment: That looks more like it, although for a team that has won 4/5 games, it's showing as .4000 whereas it should be .800 (Need to work out how to make it 3 decimal places rather than 4)

Comment: Hmm, in my test, I have a team with 4/5 wins and correctly shows 0.8000.  I don't see how it could become 0.4000.  I just put the schema in SQL Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47dc9/1 ... As far as the decimal precision, that is really more on the presentation/client side. You would control how many places to display from your application (e.g.: PHP).